# How can a custom web part read the list item fields in a display/edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to create a custom web part and programmatically attach to the display and edit forms of a list. The web part is meant to display some information (coming from another list) about the list item being displayed on the form.

I know how to add the web part to the list programmatically, but I'm having an issue trying to get the web part to read the list item being displayed on from. I know the SPForm object exposes its parent list but I cannot or don't know how to convert the form to an SPForm object. The parent of the web part is the web part manager and the parent of that is the HTML form object. But when I try convert that to an SPForm object it throws an error.

Also, even if I manage to get hold of the SPForm and its parent list, how can I get hold of the list item being displayed?

Please bear in mind that I need to avoid overwriting the default forms as it will significantly increase the development time.

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I think there is a solution, but before I respond, please answer the following question. You said you retrieve some information from another list, but how do you associate a list item to that information? Is there a lookup field that refers from one list to another? If yes, which list refers to which?